# Disable any interaction with div (click, drag, scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I have a website with jQuery full page plugin. My mobile navigation opens so transforming main window to about 80% right and draggin to view the mobile menu.

[Live preview](http://mantasmilka.com/stack) (only mobile version)

I made clicking on .section toggle .menu-open class on header, but if user drags or scrolls on section the Full Page plugin functionality distorts the view of the window.

I need to disable any interaction with .section or siwtch the default interaction with toggleClass.

I've tried:

- e.preventDefault - This disables the click on .section div to toggleClass menu-open
- pointer-events: none - Doesn't work

[image: This is how open menu should look like]

But users can still interact with the  section on the right (white div).

1. I want to allow them to click on it to toggle menu-open class, so the  window would be taken back to their main view.
2. I want to disable ability to scroll or drag the section in order to prevent jQuery Full page recalculating window position and displacing the  window while the mobile menu is open.

This is the code which I am using in jQuery to toggle the menu and toggle the menu when clicked on section:

```
$('nav, .mobile-menu--close').click(function(e){
    $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
});
$('.section').click(function(e){
    if ($('body').hasClass('menu-open')) {
        $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
    };
});
```

I need to update this bit to detect if (user scrolls or drags '.section') prevent default jQuery Full Page functionality (slide to other section or slide) and just toggle the menu-open class.

---

Found a solution. Posted below.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Whats the actual issue here? When I click the menu, it opens distorted to begin with? Can you elaborate? Post some code, anything to give us more information.

Comment: I've added the I've tried so far as well as screenshot and some info on what I am trying to achieve. I hope I've explained my problem better. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Solution.

I've created a  which is fixed with poisitioning fixed top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 26%; background-image: linear-gradient(shadow from right to left gradient);

While menu is closed it's pointer-events: none; opacity: 0;

When menu is open it get's opacity: 1; pointer-events: all;

It absorbs any interaction from user and will act as a menu-open toggle button in jQuery. jQuery changed code below:

```
$('.mobile-shadow').click(function(e){
    $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```